# Create Array through Index of Numbers Without Pushing into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var nums = [1,2,4];
```

And I have another array filled with people

```
var people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' },
];
```

I want to create a variable that based off using the `nums` variable acting as indexes to the `people` variable.

```
// With the nums array I take each value and set it as the value of the new variable
// This is my expected output. Although this is line of code is not possible since the nums variable will be unique each time the code run.
var select_people = [people[1], people[2], people[4]];
```

I am unable to create an empty array and then push each element into the `select_people` array like so.

```
// This will not do for me
var select_people = [];

for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  select_people.push(people[nums[i]])
}
```

My question is this. How can I write this code so that I can assign the `select_people` variable without having to push the values into the array?

Comment: Wait... why exactly do you not want to push things into the `select_people` array?

Comment: `i` in your code is `undefined`.

Comment: what is your expected output or use case?

Comment: If you're looking for conciseness, you could do `var selectPeople = people.filter(function(k, i) { return nums.indexOf(i) >= 0; });`

Comment: @soktinpk, It's complicated. But all we need to know is that pushing is not an option for me.

Comment: @charlietfl  The expected output is added to the question.

Comment: How about `var selected = nums.map(function(v) {
    return people[v]; 
});`

Comment: If all you want for the `num` variable is really _acting as **indexes** to the people variable_, then just treat it like so.

Comment: @Vohuman I think that should be an answer

Comment: I'm curious. Which is faster, `map` or `filter`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's seem to be unnecessary now! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's conciseness you want, then you could try:

```
var selectPeople = people.filter(function(k, i) { return nums.indexOf(i) >= 0; });
```

Similarly, you could do (I actually prefer this):

```
var selectPeople = nums.map(function(k) { return people[k]; });
```

**Note**: This only works in modern browsers.

However, I can't think of many scenarios where using `push` is not the best option.

If it is a naming conflict, you can always wrap it in a temporary function (which works in all browsers):

```
var selectPeople = (function() {
    var temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) temp.push(people[nums[i]]);
    return temp;
})();
```

This essentially eliminates any naming conflicts (or, for example, conflicts where `selectPeople` is not a true array as it lacks a `push` method).

Comment: I'll try this out. Give me a minute or two.

Comment: It works! Thanks!!!! If you're wondering why push is not the best option. I'm using AngularJS Select2 and I'm having issues with updating the ng-model for the Select2 input field. Pushing to the ng-model variable doesn't do squat, so I have to create an entire new array.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized you `i` variable in you `for` loop:

This should work:

```
var select_people = [];

for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   select_people.push(people[nums[i]])
}
```

Comment: Ooh.. so you want to push values in your `select_people` variable.. without using `Array.push` ?

Comment: Not push. Just assign the `select_people` variable all in one line without using `Array.push`. Sorry if I'm not explaining it well. I don't even know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to achieve the same result.

```js
var people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' },
];
var nums = [1,2,4];
var j = [];
for(var i = 0, l = nums.length; i < l; i++) {
  j.push(JSON.stringify(people[nums[i]]));
}
j = '[' + j.join(',') + ']';
var selectPeople = JSON.parse(j);
console.log(selectPeople);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x=0;x<nums.length;x++){
    alert(people[nums[x]]['name']);
    // or you can define your select_people here with people[nums[x]]
    // yes, you get people[1], people[2] and people[4]
    // but, your first people is "Adam", and people[1] is "Amalie"
}
```

so if you want to take first people with "nums" valued "1", just do

```
for(x=0;x<nums.length;x++){
    alert(people[nums[x]-1]['name']);
    // or you can define your select_people here with people[nums[x]-1]
    // yes, you get people[0], people[1] and people[3]
    // your first people is "Adam", and people[0] is "Adam"
}
```